# function in setInterval waits till other process function ends node

Tags: node.js

My app makes some work then makes query to db. It is reaping every 3 seconds, the app must have only 1 active connection to db, if connection is active must wait then do it, I have tried this:

```
var state = false;
let l = 0;
function sleep(ms) {
   console.log('object');
   l++;
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function lol(orderid) {

 if (state == true) {
    await sleep(1000 + l * 1000);
    let k = await lol(orderid);
    return k;
  };

   state = true;
   let res = await getOrders(`(${orderid})`, 1500, 20)
   state = false;
   return res;
}


let orderid = 14136377;

setInterval(async () => {
   let m = await lol(orderid++);
   console.log(m[0]['json_build_object']['order']['orderid']);
}, 1000);
```

Now it's making query for sorted ID witch every time incremented and output it.This is results

[image]

condition  `if (state == true || l >0 )` don't give response,all interval  calls stays alive.
As you can see sometimes it's not consecutive. How to make it consecutive?
Are there any better ways to make this ?

Comment: What do you mean "not ordered"? If you're referring to sort order, looks fine to me

Comment: this is response from db,after `14136394` response was `14136396`,I mean it isn't consecutive.

Comment: You say it's repeating every 3 seconds, the second argument in `setInterval` is 1 second

Comment: It's for test :)

Comment: If a connection could last longer than three seconds then why not just do the DB work then set an interval for three seconds to do it all over again? How close to three-second intervals do you actually need?

Comment: Do you mean collect query data and after response make query for next interval data?

Answer (score 0):

If think this will be enough.

```
let state = false;
let data = [];

getorerids().then(res => {
  if(state){
    data.push(res);
  }else {
    state = true;
    dbcall(res);
  }
});

dbcall(ids)
.then(res =>{
  dosmtwithids(res);
  if(data[0]){
    return dbcall(data.pop());
  }else {
    state = false;
  }
});

dosmtwithids(){
  .......
};

setInterval(getorerids, 3000);
```